# Why is a program using the .NET framework smaller than the same program in unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, c, optimization

I have the following program written in unmanaged C code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

const TCHAR g_szClassName[] = _T("SkeletonAppWindowClass");

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam);
ATOM RegisterWCEX(HINSTANCE hInstance);
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd);

ATOM RegisterWCEX(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    ZeroMemory(&wcex, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hIcon =
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = g_szClassName;

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

BOOL CALLBACK EnumChildProc(HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HFONT hfDefault = (HFONT)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
    SendMessage(hWnd, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hfDefault, 0L);
    return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT Msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    static HWND hButton;
    switch (Msg)
    {
    case WM_CREATE:
        hButton = CreateWindow(_T("BUTTON"), _T("Say Hi"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD, 130, 230, 70, 20, hWnd, NULL, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL);
        break;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if ((HWND)lParam == hButton)
        {
            MessageBox(0, _T("Hello World!"), _T("Information"), MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION);
        }
        break;
    case WM_CLOSE:
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, Msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    MSG Msg;

    RegisterWCEX(hInstance);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, g_szClassName, _T("Simple Window"), WS_VISIBLE | WS_SYSMENU, 100, 100, 350, 370, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_SHOW);
    EnumChildWindows(hWnd, EnumChildProc, 0L);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    while (GetMessage(&Msg, NULL, 0, 0) > 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&Msg);
        DispatchMessage(&Msg);
    }
    return Msg.wParam;
}
```

All it does is create a simple window, which, when clicked, pops up a Message Box that says "Hello World!"

This program is 10KB in size in Release mode with the `/O1` (minimize space) optimization.

Then, when I create a "Windows Forms Application" in C# and create a button on the form whose event handler is this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hello World", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

When compiled in Release mode, the C# executable is only 8KB in size.  This is counterintuitive; I would have expected the unmanaged program to be more compact.

Is the problem the way I coded the C program, or is there something else that I have not taken into account?

Comment: Just curious: What's so counter-intuitive about it?

Comment: Because the majority of the content of the C# functionality is contained in the .NET framework, and the unmanaged code is linked into the executable instead.

Comment: The .exe format has several non-optional sections with alignment requirements in the order of one or more kB. The "wasted" space is likely just wasted. On the other hand - I bet both files will use the same amount of disk space, a whole cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of the functionality of your programs are contained in the libraries that you're linking to. These libraries don't impact the size of your program unless for example they take more function calls to do the same behavior. That's the case in your example. The windows library requires a lot of setup and calls into the API to produce a dialog box compared to the .NET app which takes a single function call, and no config. The size of the compiled program has to do with the number of instructions to link and call the external API of the library. The unmanaged program has more instructions than the program using .NET.

Answer (score 1):

The compiling to the machine code is in runtime. Funcionalities of your code (libaries) are the installed with your .NET. So your application is smaller because it uses the installed libaries of your pc.